# Checkbox input information in an email

Tags: php, html, email, contact-form

I have some code that displays input information from a checkbox in my email  once submitted. This works absolutely fine but when a user does not make a selection from the checkboxes I want it to display 'No options checked' in my email message. How can I do this? Below is the relevant code - I need to achieve this for both of these checkboxes. I am assuming I need some sort of ELSE statement.

Code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['features'])) {
foreach($_POST['features'] as $value) {
    $check_msg1 .= "Features checked: ".$value."\n";          
}}

if(!empty($_POST['fright'])) {
foreach($_POST['fright'] as $value) {
    $check_msg2 .= "Fright checked: ".$value."\n";            
}}
```

Comment: Have you handled your `!empty` functions within your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
if(isset($_POST['features'])) {
foreach($_POST['features'] as $value) {
    $check_msg1 .= "Features checked: ".$value."\n";          
}}
else {
    $check_msg1 .= "No options checked \n";
}

if(isset($_POST['fright'])) {
foreach($_POST['fright'] as $value) {
    $check_msg2 .= "Fright checked: ".$value."\n";            
}}
else {
    $check_msg2 .= "No options checked \n";
}
```

If no options are checked, then POST will not return any value for a checkbox. Therefore, you need to check to see whether the value in the POST array has been set. Checking for 'empty' will return true even if a checkbox was checked, but it has an empty value.

Comment: It says undefined variable for check_msg1. Do I need to add this? $check_msg1 = $_POST['features'];
$check_msg2 = $_POST['fright'];

Comment: You must initialize both variables before you use them within the for loops, otherwise they only exist within the context of the loop itself and can't be used later on.

If you have not already initialized them elsewhere, then you must insert the following before the above:

`$check_msg1 = ""; `
`$check_msg2 = ""; `

Answer (score 1):

Checkbox values are not submitted once not checked, so if `$_POST['cb_name']` is empty, than nothing checked. According to this, you will need code like this(same for 'fright') :

```
if(!empty($_POST['features'])) {
   foreach($_POST['features'] as $value) {
       $check_msg1 .= "Features checked: ".$value."\n";          
   }
} else {
   $check_msg1 .= "No options checked\n"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the user hasn't checked anything there will be no $_POST['features'] or $_POST['fright']

You need to do an isset, or more precisely a ! isset

```
if ( ! isset($_POST['features']))
{
    $check_msg1 .= "No features selected.\n";
}
else
{
    foreach ($_POST['features'] as $value)
    {
        $check_msg1 .= "Features checked: " . $value . "\n";
    }
}

if ( ! isset($_POST['fright']))
{
    $check_msg2 .= "No fright selected.\n";
}
else
{
    foreach ($_POST['fright'] as $value)
    {
        $check_msg2 .= "Fright checked: " . $value . "\n";
    }
}
```